# Vue.js Vuetify Dialog Issue - Background Turns Black on Dialog Open

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am working on a Vue.js project with Vuetify and have encountered an issue with `<v-dialog>`. When I click on a card, the dialog opens as expected, but it makes the entire background black. I want the dialog to appear without affecting the background color.

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```js
<template>
  <v-container class="mx-auto">
    <v-timeline>
      <v-timeline-item
        v-for="Time in Timeline"
        :key="Time.id"
        :dot-color="Time.color"
        :icon="Time.icon"
        fill-dot
      >
        <template v-slot:opposite>
          <span
            :class="`text-body-2 font-weight-bold ${Time.color}--text`"
            v-text="Time.at"
          />
        </template>
        <v-card elevation="10" hover class="rounded-shaped" @click="showModal()">
          <v-card-title :class="`bg-${Time.color}`">
            <v-icon class="mx-2" dark>
                {{Time.icon}}
            </v-icon>
            <h2 class="text-h6  white--text font-weight-light">{{Time.title}}</h2>
            </v-card-title>
          <v-card-text>
            <span v-html="Time.description"></span>
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
        <v-dialog v-model="modal" max-width="500">
          <v-card>
            hi
          </v-card>
        </v-dialog>
      </v-timeline-item>
    </v-timeline>
  </v-container>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  components: {
  },
  data() {
      return {
          Timeline: [
              // {id:'', color:'', icon:'', at:'', justify:'', title:'', description:''},
              ],
          modal: false,
      }
  },
  methods : {
    showModal() {
      this.modal =true;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I have already tried adjusting the `scrim` attribute, and `persistent` but it doesn't seem to resolve the issue. Any insights or suggestions on how to prevent the background from turning black when the dialog is open would be greatly appreciated.

The current dialog when clicked in card is as attached below:
[image]

I am new with this and if there is any better way to add the dialog than this, I am happy to learn it.
Thank you

Comment: You'll need to provide more code and/or debugging details.  The code so far [doesn't reproduce the issue](https://shorturl.at/xzIR6).  It looks like the opacity of the overlay is somehow set to 1 which is not the default value.  Use the DOM inspector and check what CSS is being applied.  The div with class `v-overlay__scrim` should have `opacity: 0.32`